# ActiveMQ Artemis: Internal and external IP addresses

Tags: kubernetes, nat, activemq-artemis

We are running an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster in a Kubernetes cluster. All of our applications (Java/Springboot/JMS) running in the Kubernetes cluster take advantage of connecting directly to the broker instances.

However, the IP addresses from the Kubernetes Pod network are unavailable outside of the cluster. Exposing the broker instances to the public network is possible — but with different IP addresses. This is similar to hiding the Artemis cluster behind a NAT configuration. When connecting to the brokers through the public IP addresses, client applications receive cluster topology information containing IP addresses (or hostnames?) that are unreachable outside of the cluster.

Is there any way to deal with “internal” and “external” IP addresses and/or hostnames and make topology discovery work for cluster-external applications?

And, related (I am not a Java developer): Is there any way to log received topology information for JMS applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis CORE client provides the `useTopologyForLoadBalancing` url parameter to disable the use of the cluster topology information for load balancing, i.e.

```
tcp://localhost:61616?useTopologyForLoadBalancing=false
```

The log of the cluster topology information can be enabled setting the `TRACE` for the `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core` logger in the `logging.properties` file, see the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/logging.html), i.e.

```
loggers=...,org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core

logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.message.level=TRACE

handler.CONSOLE.level=TRACE

handler.FILE.level=TRACE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Domenico. The hint `useTopologyForLoadBalancing=false` seems to be quite useful. Regarding logging, your hint does not apply to clients, does it?

Comment: To enable logging on the client side you need to include the JBoss logging jars in your library and to set the following properties: `java.util.logging.manager` and `logging.configuration`, see the documentation at https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/logging.html#logging-in-a-client-or-with-an-embedded-server

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on topology discovery from outside clients. What you can do is either provide a list of the external ips or have a router / load-balancer in front of your cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. We already have a load balancer in front of the cluster but looks like this only makes sense when connecting with `useTopologyForLoadBalancing=false` as mentioned by Domenico (at least for the CORE protocol, other protocols are not affected by the topology discovery issue).

Comment: Yes, it just depends on setting it: you can define it is the URL or at the connection factory level. that's what I meant by "You can't rely on topology discovery from outside clients." Should have been more precise :)